# Permission denied while running shell script from crontab

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, runtime-error, cron

I login to my id in Linux and then login as a **superuser** as I don't have home directory. when I set it up on crontab, I get an error:

```
 /bin/sh: /export/home/****/somefoldername/Check.sh: Permission denied.
```

I have given complete access to the file by issuing:

```
chmod 777
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: The crontab process (its user) must also have access to the folder somefoldername. And, if /export/home is located on a network file system (as the name suggests ;-) ), the user that runs the crontab process must have privileges on the network file system. In that case a solution depends on your setup. Ask your network administrator to help you.

Comment: somefolername is the superuser..I don't have a home directory, so I login as su - somefoldername and scheduled it from there.

Comment: You switch to the user `somefoldername` which is not the superuser (root) by calling `su - somefoldername` on the commandline. [It is possible that somefoldername is the superuser if it has the userid 0 ;-) ]. One problem could be that the folder `somefoldername` has not sufficient rights to change into it and execute a script/program in it. On the other hand,  the path `export/home` make me think that the home dirs are on a network filesystem. Then there might be problems for crontab  with acces rights to the network. That's a case for the network administrator.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will check with the network administrator

Answer (score 0):

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
0 *    * * *   root    /root/scr/script.sh
```

I don't know which linux distribution you are using but on Ubuntu you can specify the user the crontab should be running with.

Comment: I am using Redhat Linux.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have "user" column.